# Intellij Idea 13 SVN Accessing Svn Working Copy Database

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I've installed Intellij Idea 13 today. I've existing maven/svn projects. Opening them with Idea 13 gives me hundreds of error messages like:

> 07:15:41 Some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database.

on event log.

Also on 'Subversion Working Copies Information' tab at 'Changes' tab, there are some entries like:

> URL: svn: E200030: Invalid expression
>
> Format:unknown Change
>
> Depth: unknown

I'm using TortoiseSvn on my PC with version information:

> TortoiseSVN 1.7.11, Build 23600 - 64 Bit , 2012/12/12 19:08:52
>
> Subversion 1.7.8,
>
> apr 1.4.6
>
> apr-utils 1.3.12
>
> neon 0.29.6
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
>
> zlib 1.2.7

How can I solve this?

EDIT: In idea.exe (32Bit one) I don't get those messages. In idea64.exe, those errors occur.

Comment: You're brave switching to X.0.0... I always wait for X.0.2 or .0.3 with jetbrains releases :)

Comment: You have point but prerequisite of this version was uninstalling the other one, so I'm stuck here :)

Comment: And that's kind of why I'm waiting a week... have been using IntelliJ since version 7 and have "been here" before.

Comment: If you say they will release another update in a week then I can wait.

Answer (score 4):

i find a way;

Go to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2\bin
```

and edit idea.exe.vmoptions

Add below line and restart

```
-Duser.language=en
```

Comment: make sure you add that line to idea64.exe.vmoptions if you are using 64 bit